# Need help obtaining Content Owner Id

Tags: youtube-api

I'm struggling with retrieving the Content Owner-based YouTube Analytics Data.  From this discussion ([Obtaining the current user's YouTube content owner id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209606/obtaining-the-current-users-youtube-content-owner-id)), I learned that I need to query youtubePartner.contentOwners.list(fetchMine=true) to obtain the content owner info, of which the Id will be found.

My struggle is that when I call youtubePartner.contentOwners.list(fetchMine=true), I receive the reason "accessNotConfigured".  I'm not sure why: I have YouTube Analytics enabled in the APIs Console for my app, and I have the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner scope configured in OAuth2 list of scopes during authentication.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may have not enabled Partner API in your [devconsole](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0) or your account may not be linked to a CMS account.

Comment: Ibrahim, thanks for the response.  I currently have AdSense Management API, Analytics API, YouTube Analytics API and YouTube Data API enabled.  I couldn't find an API that references Partner.  What API could I be missing?

Comment: I forgot to add that I have https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner in my OAuth2 scope.

Comment: You also need to enable Partner API, but to see Partner API in options, you need to be whitelisted for that API. Talk with your Technical Account Manager to get whitelisted.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  Sorry to do this, but...Technical Account Manager?  Is that a Google employee?  I really appreciate the help, but I have no idea how to get whitelisted.  Can you give me a bit more detail as to who I should be talking to?

Comment: To use Partner API, you need to be a partner. http://www.youtube.com/yt/partners/ Then you can request to be whitelisted from your partner representative.

Comment: The account I'm using is a YouTube Partner account, but I cannot find anywhere within the YouTube partner pages of the account that I can contact a human being for assistance, or request a whitelist of any kind.  I see no reference on any page or link to a Technical Account Manager.  I'm sorry to be so dumb, but are there any more details you can provide to help me get whitelisted?

Comment: Can you let me know your CMS email address?

Comment: Ibrahim, apparently I didn't give you a proper email address?  I obviously need help here.  Thanks.

Comment: I see that you are not a content id partner, please talk with your partner manager to be a content id partner first

Comment: It's true that I'm not a content id partner.  But all I'm trying to do is get the YouTube earnings from the API, like I can see it from my YouTube page.  How do I do that using the API without being a Partner?